# How do I automatically update ipvs information?

Tags: kubernetes, kube-proxy, ipvs

I am using kubernetes and using kube-proxy mode as ipvs(scheduler: lc).

ipvsadm table information is not updated when pod is increased(replicas).

Therefore, in order to load balance with the new pod, the service must be deleted and regenerated.

Is there a way to automatically renew ipvs without recreating the service?

Comment: That sounds like you may have found a bug in the IPVS support. It should be updating automatically with the Endpoints object in the API.

Comment: My kube-proxy config looks like this:

ipvs:
      excludeCIDRs: null
      minSyncPeriod: 0s
      scheduler: "lc"
      strictARP: false
      syncPeriod: 0s
      tcpFinTimeout: 0s
      tcpTimeout: 0s
      udpTimeout: 0s

If it is normal, does it need to be renewed without giving a separate option?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve a time to read the  [**about page**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit theses links to learn [**how to ask a question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)  and [**how to create a minimal, reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to get better and faster answer! Please provide as much details in your reproduction, including warnings, errors, so we can reproduce your scenario and help not only you, but enable you to help others with similar issues!